# Installing GNU arm Toolchain?

Tags: software-installation

Please, do tell me the procedure to compile and install the GNU arm Toolchain "arm-2010q1-202-arm-none-linux-gnueabi" which I downloaded from codesourcey website.

I could not find the deb packages.

Answer (score 6):

You probably downloaded a `.tar.gz` file, which contains the compiled toolchain. In this case, just do something like:

```
tar xvf arm-2010q1-202-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.tar.gz
```

Then you should have an `arm-2010q1` (or similar) directory. The actual toolchain executables are in the `bin` subdirectory.

However, if you're looking for an ARM cross-compiler, there is one pre-packaged in Ubuntu, which may be easier to get running. It's in the `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` package - to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Comment: I downloaded arm-2010q1-202-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2. It caontains source files for the toolchain. I was asking how to compile it.
Well, thanks for the information.

Comment: Do you really need to compile your own toolchain? It's one of the least fun parts of software development.

Comment: May be it is? but anyways I get to learn something and this will help when there will be an urgent need to compile a toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

If you had downloaded the GNU arm toolchain from Codebench, you can install from terminal with the following:

```
/bin/sh ./arm-2010q1-202-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.bin
```

A GUI screen opens for installation. Default path for installation is shown, you can change it to `/opt`